# How to Change list view's height progmmatically..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to know how to change height of the list view programmatically.

Is it possible to change the child items height for individual list item...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noby if you want to change the hight of Child items you add new item_row layouts for each child and change it height as you want and inflate it using View getView method ...........

If youi want to change height of listview....

**list.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(155, 115));**

**LayoutParams.fill_parent  and LayoutParams.wrap_content**

enter your listview width and height in paranthases.,,,, and in your xml file only listiew in relative layout...........

Answer (score 21):

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = whatYouWant;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
```

Comment: what about wrap_content and match_parents?